# Как реализовать поиск по значению во вложенном объекте в Spring Data Repository

Tags: spring, jpa, crud

у меня есть объект Customer, в котором есть объект Addresses, в кором есть, допустим, номер дома. Как мне получить список Customer по номеру дома?

Как я примерно вижу:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
    List<Customer> findByAddressesWhereHouseNumber(int houseNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе надо составить сигнатуру метода согласно [правилам](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions) для поиска во вложенных объектах:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
    List<Customer> findByAddressesHouseNumber(int houseNumber);
}
```

Или же ты можешь явно задать запрос

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
    @Query("select c from Customer c where c.adresses.houseNumber=:houseNumber")
    List<Customer> mySuperFind(@Param("houseNumber") int houseNumber);
}
```

Comment: блин, до теста долго.